# Pytest mock return an object that can make another fake function call

Tags: mocking, pytest

I have code that looks like this:

```
query = get_query(f"export_user_{user_component}").render()
```

where get_query is a custom function that returns an object with a `render` method. How do I mock this in a test?

I have a test like this:

```
@mock.patch("de_etl.operations.user_data_export.components.get_query", side_effect=mock_get_query)
        @mock.patch("de_etl.operations.user_data_export.util.execute_query", side_effect=mock_execute_query)
        def test__export_user_empty_profile(self, execute_query, get_query):
            with pytest.raises(Exception) as exc:
                de_etl.operations.user_data_export.components._export_user(user_id="12345678910", db=mock.Mock())

            assert exc.value.args[0] == "User Profile must exist"
```

but I get an error: `'str' object has no attribute 'render'`

which makes sense since my `mock_query` just does this:

```
def mock_get_query(name):
    return name
```

but I need the mock_query to return an object with a `render` function. How do I do this?

I did something like this... is this okay?

```
def mock_get_query(sql_to_mock):
    def mock_get_query_called(actual_sql):
        if sql_to_mock == actual_sql:
            mocked_query = mock.Mock()
            mocked_query.render.return_value = sql_to_mock
            return mocked_query
        else:
            mocked_query = mock.Mock()
            mocked_query.render.return_value = actual_sql
            return mocked_query

    return mock_get_query_called
```

Comment: Instead of returning a string `name`, you can create a dummy test class with `render` method defined, or you can return a mock object and set a return_value for its `render` call. Is there any reason not to follow one of those two approaches?

Comment: Mind giving a quick example and showing? I eventually did something like my edit above

Comment: Can you explain why you need the if else clause? if you enter the if clause then sql_to_mock == actual_sql, so you effectively return actual_sql and also in the else you return actual_sql. Might do the logic without it and have a simpler method. Another question would be - why do you need the inner method (unless of course you need a complex logic in the inner method and be dependent on the outer method parameter value).

Comment: It just adheres to the logic of my actual code. What did you mean create a dummy test class with render?

Comment: A dummy class with a render method is a class you define in your test, instead of returning a magic mock.

If you do need some complex logic, it seems that your solution is adequate.